# Formatting Date in JS controller in Salesforce

Tags: lightning, javascript, community

We have a requirement that the user will give the Date format in the text field, we have to validate the date format whether it is valid or not based on the Salesforce Localization method.

But SF localization method is not understanding a few of the valid formats like DD/MM/YYYY and giving output as Invalid Date.

Eg:

```
$A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), 'DD/MM/YYYY') ;
    output: "31/12/2019"
$A.localizationService.formatDate('31/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') ;
    **final output: "Invalid Date"**
```

Is there a way in JS to find whether the date is valid or not. We tried `Date.parse` but it also gives NaN (`Date.parse('30/12/2019')`)

Comment: are you using date picker to input the date?

Comment: No, just text field @r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation `localizationService` supports only  ISO 8601.

> The date parameter can be a String, Number, or most typically a
>   JavaScript Date. If you provide a String value, use [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format to
>   avoid parsing warnings.

`31/12/2019` is not as per ISO 8601 format.

You either need to convert that to the supported format or a valid Date object in JS.

[JavaScript Date Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)